# Surjection from proper class to ordinals

Tags: set-theory

If $C$ is a proper class, then there is a surjection $s : C \to \textbf{On}$. Here, **On** is the proper class of ordinals.

My idea for such a surjection is to show that the class $\{ \text{rank}(a) : a \in C \}$ is exactly the same as the class of ordinals. I'm pretty sure the idea is right, but I'm not sure about how to show this.

Comment: Not necessarily exactly the same. But you can show that every proper class of ordinals can be mapped onto the ordinals themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The idea isn't exactly right. Consider, for example, the class $C$ of *limit ordinals* - $C$ has no element of rank (say) $17$.

However, you're moving in the right direction. If $C$ is a proper class, then the class of ranks of elements of $C$ forms an unbounded class of ordinals; can you see how to surject an unbounded class of ordinals onto all the ordinals? (HINT: there's a very nice recursive construction here. First think about how you'd surject an arbitrary infinite set of finite ordinals onto all of $\omega$ ...)